# Unexpected keyword argument 'instances' Vertex Google AI

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I try to return from these text rows

```
tH3 Oth3r5
1ncept10n
F1ght Clu8
4.th3.=th3ers.1n.th3.sh3ll
```

the real name like

```
The Others
Inception
Fight Club
The Others in the Shell
```

I take a look from vertex google AI

https://imgur.com/AGPIo4W.png

So I tried to convert into code to make request to code-bison model

```
import os
import vertexai
from vertexai.language_models import TextGenerationModel

vertexai.init(project="myprojectname", location="us-central1")

parameters = {
    "candidate_count": 1,
    "max_output_tokens": 1024,
    "temperature": 0.9
}

model = TextGenerationModel.from_pretrained("text-bison")

names = ["tH3 Oth3r5", "1ncept10n", "F1ght Clu8", "4.th3.=th3ers.1n.th3.sh3ll"]

for name in names:
    response = model.predict(
        instances=[{"content": name}],  # Cambia 'input' in 'instances'
        **parameters
    )
    print(f"Input: {name}")
    print(f"Generated Name: {response.text}")
```

but I get this error

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SCRIPT\60_nomineurali>python vertex.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SCRIPT\60_nomineurali\vertex.py", line 18, in <module>
    response = model.predict(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: _TextGenerationModel.predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instances'
```

Comment: As the error says, `model.predict` does [not appear to take an `instances` argument](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/vertexai.language_models.TextGenerationModel#vertexai_language_models_TextGenerationModel_predict). Where are you seeing that it does?